# How to prevent raw exception information appearing on JSP in Spring MVC 3.0 app?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, error-handling

While testing my Spring app, I uploaded a file that exceeded the maximum allowed size configured in the app.

Consequently, the following message appeared on the JSP, visible to the user:

```
Error
Exception: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: 
something went wrong here; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileUploadIOException
```

What would I need to change to present a more user-friendly message on the JSP for the user?

For example:

```
Uploaded file exceeds maximum allowed size of 25MB.
```

Answer (score 1):

*I have not done Spring MVC before but I think Spring can do it*.

Use Message Resources (ResourceBundle). You will have to catch the exception and create a error page where the message of the error can be displayed.

Spring uses **ResourceBundleMessageSource** for message resources. This [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/) (however too simple) shows you how to configure one and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html).

```
public class MyExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver{
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex){
        return new ModelAndView("jsp_to_show_error_message.jsp").
                 addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Create a new jsp `jsp_to_show_error_message.jsp` and put `${message}` somewhere within it. Configure `MyExceptionResolver` in your xml. If you are using annotations based controller, read [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s09.html).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving Spring outside consideration, the Servlet API offers the possibility to attach custom error pages to certain exceptions. In this particular example, it's a matter of adding the following entry to `web.xml`.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException</exception-type>
    <location>errors/upload.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This way you can supply a fully custom error page in default webpage layout in flavor of `errors/upload.jsp`.